# playJoin is undefined, unexpected end of input, and files not importing correctly

Tags: javascript, html

I have a very simple JavaScript function that loops through some songs that are in an audio folder. However, the below code yields:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: playJoin is not defined
```

Even though it should be defined as a function? I ran it through a validator, and it is syntactically correct. Another issue that I am having is importing the audio. Even when I change the file path, it doesn't update, even when clearing the cache.

```
Path: /audio/join-page-audio1.mp3, Status Code: 404 Not Found
```

The full code block in question is the following:

```
<audio id="join1">
    <source src="/src/audio/join-page-audio1.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
</audio>

<script>
number = 1
joinSong = "join" + number

function playJoin() {
    let fn = function(number) {
        let joinSong = "join" + number;
        let audio = document.getElementById(joinSong);
        audio.play();
        audio.onended = function() {
            if (number <= 1) {
                fn(number + 1);
            } else {
                fn(1);
            }
        }
    };
    fn(1);
}
</script>
```

All of this is in the HTML head, and it gets called by the *body*'s *onload* event.

Comment: first problem... fn(1) is inaccessible due to its closure scope.

Comment: @sandeepjoshi Is what I edited better? It still wouldn't show why playJoin is not defined at all.

Comment: Is this code is inline or external JS file? And if external, do you use `async` or `defer` to load the file?

Comment: it is inline (```<script>``` in HTML file). I mentioned this in the question.

Comment: I found out that I was editing the wrong files. Anyway, is there a way to autoplay audio onload of the window without ```$(window).on("load", function() {});```? It keeps saying ```Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: play() failed because the user didn't interact with the document first.``` due to a new update on autoplaying videos and such.

Comment: great you solved it... regarding autoplay it is mandatory for user to interact with document first. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64089599/how-to-avoid-chrome-autoplay-policy-on-js-code/64095890#64095890

Comment: @sandeepjoshi I found the ```Feature-Policy: autoplay 'self'``` header. Will this help? I would prefer if there was audio playing when the page loaded. It's not user-friendly to have to click a button to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can rely on feature policy but it can't guarantee autoplay so you should be prepared for fallback...

***Autoplay availability***

> As a general rule, you can assume that media will be allowed to autoplay only if at least one of the following is true:
>
> 1. The audio is muted or its volume is set to 0
> 2. The user has interacted with the site (by clicking, tapping, pressing keys, etc.)
> 3. If the site has been whitelisted; this may happen either automatically if the browser determines that the user engages with media frequently, or manually through preferences or other user interface features
> 4. If the autoplay feature policy is used to grant autoplay support to an  and its document.
>
> Otherwise, the playback will likely be blocked. The exact situations that result in blocking, and the specifics of how sites become whitelisted vary from browser to browser, but the above are good guidelines to go by.

*Put another way, playback of any media that includes audio is generally blocked if the playback is programmatically initiated in a tab which has not yet had any user interaction. Browsers may additionally choose to block under other circumstances.*

for more detail visit [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Media/Autoplay_guide)